# How do I get OpenJDK 16 to talk with an SSL enabled nginx server?

Tags: java, nginx, ssl

I'm running a spring boot application that needs to make an https call to an nginx server.  The application is running on CentOS 7 with OpenJDK 16.

Following [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-7093246A-31A3-4304-AC5F-5FB6400405E2) more or less, I gathered a list of all the ciphers available to the JVM:

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

In nginx, I have the following:

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    resolver 169.254.169.253;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ciphers ...keys here...;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam;
```

I've tried every one of the ciphers available to my JVM in place of `...keys here...` and they all result in nginx failing to start with:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list("...") failed (SSL: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match)
```

I can add a list more like I would expect, such as:

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
```

nginx starts at this point - and most applications like Chrome, wget, etc are fine with it.  Oracle's JDK 11 on my laptop also connects to it without issue.  However the OpenJDK based application refuses to connect:

```
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "1F F7 66 B2 EB 52 F0 3A 99 E6 9B A7 10 1A 85 E1 0C FF DC 36 06 C7 52 38 0C 8A 27 9F 21 AA 0E 7D",
  "session id"          : "70 E0 79 AB 78 7B 48 22 41 22 1E 38 64 01 BF E8 7D E0 2C DD BA 08 09 00 20 B2 39 8D 53 B4 65 A2",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_
WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AE
S_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D
), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F)]",
...
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1C|http-nio-8080-exec-7|2022-03-21 22:37:28.252 UTC|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
```

I also ran across [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Cipher_Suites) - I'm assuming this means that the JDK cipher named `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` for instance should be `DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` in nginx/OpenSSL.  So I tried a modified cipher list in nginx of:

```
ssl_ciphers DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA;
```

but still the same result.  In the nginx logs:

```
2022/03/22 06:05:55 [info] 74#74: *22 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141F7065:SSL routines:final_key_share:no suitable key share) while SSL handshaking, client: #.#.#.#, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

and in the Java service logs:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 06:05:56.332 UTC|ClientHello.java:652|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "A9 28 13 AB 6F 82 B6 F1 88 E9 2C C9 CE 84 55 15 84 9E 25 E9 57 72 C3 BA CF 1C 9B 45 3D 13 28 7F",
  "session id"          : "5E F8 0E 52 83 A9 C2 AF DE 6C BD E4 D7 3C A5 FD D9 00 6F 1C D7 CA 07 E0 63 EF C4 24 CF 57 9F A1",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCAA), TLS_DH
...
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 06:05:56.334 UTC|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 06:05:56.335 UTC|TransportContext.java:361|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
...
```

I can't seem to find any good documentation on adding additional ciphers to the JVM, only enabling ones that are present but not enabled for some reason.  I've seen some vague references to BouncyCastle, but unclear how to properly use that for this purpose, especially since I won't be creating the sockets myself (using a library that needs to make the call).

I also can't seem to figure out how to configure nginx/OpenSSL to enable additional ciphers to support what the Java application is expecting.  I'm using nginx 1.21.6 and OpenSSL 1.1.1k.

So...  How do I add/configure ciphers to make the two play well together?

Comment: (1) nginx uses OpenSSL which has its own names for ciphersuites, different from the official (RFC) names which Java uses; the `openssl-ciphers` man page shows the mapping (except for the new 1.3 suites, which are different) (2) where is this openjdk 16 from? I don't see any in the CentOS repository (only 6,7,8,11) and from your 'available' list it doesn't have any suites using EC, which 'standard' Java has included since j7; RedHat and thus CentOS packages removed EC in the past, but that was fixed well before j16. ...

Comment: ... Your previous Q also showed supported_groups not including (and key_share not using) EC groups, and nginx complaining about key_share. And your logged CLientHello doesn't include TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 from the available list, which is weird. But the OpenSSL-named DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 and DHE-AES256-GCM-SHA384 in your nginx config do match TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 in your Java list, so I don't see why one of those doesn't work. I'll try to look at the code for ideas.

Comment: PS re your previous: this is definitely not related to your server certificate(s); that _never_ causes handshake_failure, plus this error is clearly happening before the cert is even transmitted.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 - The JDK comes from https://openjdk.java.net/install/ (although we host the tarball locally so we aren't subject to 3rd party outages).  I tried to start from scratch on this question, which is why some of the details are a little different.

Comment: I'd much rather use the OpenJDK, but to try a different angle I downloaded the Oracle 16.02 JRE and tried that - that seems to connect without issue (no change to the nginx ssl settings).  There's an issue further downstream, but it gets passed all of the SSL handshakes to a legitimate response from nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the issue came down to an outdated installation of OpenSSL.

I mistakenly read the OpenSSL version from the docker host (1.1.1x) instead of from the container (don't remember the version, but was from 2017).  Unfortunately, this can't easily be updated in CentOS 7 - nothing from the package manager, and compiling from source runs into all sorts of issues.  But once past those issues, the list of ciphers was about 5x as long and the connection worked fine.

I then switched to Ubuntu 20.04, which made the installation of OpenSSL much easier (1.1.1f comes standard from the package manager).  SSL handshake went through as expected.

On to the next problem - even with a successful SSL negotiation, for some reason all SSL connections are timing out after 25ms...  but that'll be another topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71577942/10525932) for anyone going down the same rathole as I am).