# Why am I getting an SSL socket timeout connecting to Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I think this question can be rewritten to "Using Spring Boot and keycloak-spring-boot-starter, what happens after KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve()?"

I have a custom keycloak config resolver:

```
public class CustomKeycloakConfigResolver
        extends KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver {
    ...
    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(final HttpFacade.Request request) {
        LOGGER.debug("-----------------------------------------------");
        LOGGER.debug("Resolving Deployment for {}", request.getURI());
        ...
        LOGGER.trace("---------- CREATING KEYCLOAK DEPLOYMENT ---------");
        KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment =
                KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig);
        LOGGER.trace("---------- /CREATED KEYCLOAK DEPLOYMENT ---------");

        return keycloakDeployment;
```

This pulls the KeycloakDeployment configuration from our database instead of from application.properties.  Testing on a local docker swarm cluster, it works like a charm (but this is only on one machine, without SSL enabled, etc).

Pushing out to our QA environment (nginx on one machine with TLS termination, REST service on another, Keycloak on another, database provided by RDS), the generation of a KeycloakDeployment goes off without a hitch.  This includes reaching out to `.well-known/openid-configuration` and resolving all of the Keycloak URLs, and printing both of the final trace() statements.

Almost immediately after (within 10-30ms) creating the KeycloakDeployment and returning it to the keycloak-spring-boot-starter framework, I receive a `SocketTimeoutException` exception.  I can't tell from the exception what the system is trying to do when throws this exception, and I haven't been able to tell from https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak what the workflow is after the deployment is "resolved()".

So - what happens next?

1. A secured method is accessed
2. Spring Boot auth hands off to Keycloak auth
3. Keycloak auth generates a custom KeycloakDeployment
4. KeycloakDeployment is resolved - reaches out to Keycloak service and obtains the OIDC configuration
5. KeycloakDeployment is passed back to Keycloak auth framework
6. ... Something happens that throws an immediate socket timeout exception...
7. Method is never invoked

How do I figure out what's happening in step 6?  I find it hard to believe it's an actual socket timeout after only 20ms, and everything I think it should be accessing is up and responsive.  But I'm willing to be wrong...

**---- Original Question ----**

I'm trying to get Keycloak working with a Spring Boot REST service behind an nginx proxy.  TLS is terminated at the nginx server.  Everything is in docker containers, but on separate machines (no kube, no swarm, etc).

Everything seems good.  I can login to the master realm, create a new realm, add users, etc.  However when the REST service tries to contact the Keycloak server (through the nginx proxy), I'm getting an SSL timeout error:

```
2022-03-22 18:59:13.384  INFO 26 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Loaded URLs from https://hostname/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.409 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:1672|handling exception (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
...
```

Thing is, this "timeout" happens almost instantaneously after the .well-known/openid-configuration response, so I'm skeptical it's even actually a timeout, unless the threshold is set to like 10ms by default or something.

I cranked up javax.net logging with `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:all");`, and I can't see anything obvious:

```
2022-03-22 18:59:13.384  INFO 26 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Loaded URLs from https://hostname/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.385 UTC|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:331|WRITE: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.385 UTC|SSLCipher.java:1770|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
  0000: 07 00 00 00 03 63 6F 6D   6D 69 74                 .....commit
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.388 UTC|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:346|Raw write (
  0000: 17 03 03 00 23 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 80 9C 76 46  ....#.........vF
  0010: 44 FA F9 3A A4 9B A1 B2   D8 9B 6A 69 76 C7 1A 3D  D..:......jiv..=
  0020: 94 C4 40 D2 D8 F2 E4 7E                            ..@.....
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.388 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:488|Raw read (
  0000: 17 03 03 00 23                                     ....#
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.388 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 35
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.388 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:488|Raw read (
  0000: 15 13 12 41 88 AD 18 6F   B8 5E 25 90 9D BA 23 BF  ...A...o.^%...#.
  0010: B3 A5 A9 5E 61 FA 77 BD   AE A4 C0 57 B2 1D 5B 18  ...^a.w....W..[.
  0020: E8 C7 77                                           ..w
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.388 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:247|READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 35
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.388 UTC|SSLCipher.java:1672|Plaintext after DECRYPTION (
  0000: 07 00 00 01 00 00 00 00   00 00 00                 ...........
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.388 UTC|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:331|WRITE: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 21
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.389 UTC|SSLCipher.java:1770|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
  0000: 11 00 00 00 03 53 45 54   20 61 75 74 6F 63 6F 6D  .....SET autocom
  0010: 6D 69 74 3D 31                                     mit=1
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.390 UTC|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:346|Raw write (
  0000: 17 03 03 00 2D 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 81 6B 87 27  ....-........k.'
  0010: 9C 91 53 E2 F8 70 1C D4   FA F3 4A 79 1B B0 11 05  ..S..p....Jy....
  0020: 13 3E 4F 10 A8 E8 43 B3   BB FA 1E 48 82 DF 59 25  .>O...C....H..Y%
  0030: CF 9D                                              ..
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.392 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:488|Raw read (
  0000: 17 03 03 00 23                                     ....#
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.392 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 35
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.392 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:488|Raw read (
  0000: 15 13 12 41 88 AD 18 70   E3 20 7E 21 DA B0 24 28  ...A...p. .!..$(
  0010: EF 6D EB BC 5C CE 5D 94   1D BC 04 BB F9 D1 3D 72  .m..\.].......=r
  0020: 0C 71 83                                           .q.
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.392 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:247|READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 35
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.393 UTC|SSLCipher.java:1672|Plaintext after DECRYPTION (
  0000: 07 00 00 01 00 00 00 02   00 00 00                 ...........
)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|18|http-nio-8080-exec-3|2022-03-22 18:59:13.409 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:1672|handling exception (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
...
```

So between the well-known configuration call and the final timeout exception:

```
18:59:13.384
18:59:13.409
```

all of 25ms passes by - seems hard to believe there would be a legitimate timeout exception thrown, but I can't seem to get any more clue as to what is causing the timeout.  The keycloak service definitely IS reachable, and responds quite quickly.

Nothing at all in the Keycloak logs, and not terribly much in the nginx logs:

```
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:56 +0000] [200] "POST /auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1" "https://web.mycompany.com/"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:57 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:57 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
2022/03/22 19:19:57 [info] 73#73: *659 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:57 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:57 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:58 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:58 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
2022/03/22 19:19:58 [info] 73#73: *670 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
2022/03/22 19:19:58 [info] 73#73: *668 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:58 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:58 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:58 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:58 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:59 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:59 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs HTTP/1.1" "-"
2022/03/22 19:19:59 [info] 73#73: *677 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
2022/03/22 19:19:59 [info] 73#73: *675 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:59 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:59 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:19:59 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:20:00 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
2022/03/22 19:20:00 [info] 73#73: *664 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
2022/03/22 19:20:00 [info] 73#73: *666 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
2022/03/22 19:20:00 [info] 73#73: *672 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
2022/03/22 19:20:00 [info] 73#73: *682 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
2022/03/22 19:20:00 [info] 73#73: *684 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
2022/03/22 19:20:00 [info] 74#74: *686 client #.#.#.# closed keepalive connection
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:20:00 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:20:00 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:20:01 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- AUTH  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:20:01 +0000] [200] "GET /auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs HTTP/1.1" "-"
[--- REST  ---] [22/Mar/2022:19:20:01 +0000] [401] "GET /api/v1/stuff HTTP/1.1" "https://web.mycompany.com/"
```

Any help as to what's going on?

**Other notes:**
I've gone through the [Setting Up a load balancer or proxy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy) instructions from Keycloak.  Specifically, the nginx server has the following:

```
    upstream AUTH {
      server #.#.#.#:8080;
      server #.#.#.#:8080;
    }
    ...
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://AUTH;
```

I think that covers bullet points 1 and 2.

Bullet point 3 is covered by the keycloak server.  The standalone-ha.xml file has:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="true">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" proxy-address-forwarding="${env.PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING:false}" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="applicationSSC" proxy-address-forwarding="${env.PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING:false}" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
                </host>
            </server>
```

and the container is launched with the environment variable

```
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
```

I've verified with a false login that Keycloak is seeing the end user's IP address rather than the nginx server:

```
15:17:07,304 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-14) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=#.#.#.#, error=user_not_found, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=https://host.name/auth/admin/master/console/#/realms/MyRealm/login-settings, code_id=..., username=foo, authSessionParentId=..., authSessionTabId=...
```

Where `#.#.#.#` is my IP address.