How to resolve java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunjSSE...?
I'm getting an error message when trying to connect a Java client application to a C++ Server using TLS. The C++ server is using openssl 3 for all its crypto operations.   All the certificates were created using openssl 3 as well.
The error message the Java client application displays is:
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunjSSE, class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext).  

From the above message and research, I presume the client and server cannot agree on an algorithm to authenticate the client?   So the big question is how can I fix this?
Root certificate is self-signed.  This is all for testing in a development environment.   The signature algorithm for the client certificate is sha256withRSAEncryption
Java application uses the Java OpenJDK 11.  Operating system is Red Hat 9.1.  Note: for these tests both the client and server are on the same virtual machine.
I enabled debugging of the SSL connection.  I believe the default TLS configuration is being used.
The root, server and client certificates were all created using openssl 3 and the certificates state they are using rsaEncryption with SHA256.
I enabled SSL handshake debugging and below is the updated output:
$  java  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake  -jar MYGUI.jar

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|Thread-0|2024-05-07 22:37:42.938 EDT|SSLCipher.java:464|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|Thread-0|2024-05-07 22:37:42.949 EDT|SSLCipher.java:464|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry =  ChaCha20-Poly1305 KeyUpdate 2^37. CHACHA20-POLY1305:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472


Not sure what other information that I could provide that would help figure this out?   I'll be glad to post anything that's needed.
Please any help at all would be appreciated, I've been at this for far too long!
Below is the updated test client certificate that I'm using to connect to the server:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            36:3a:28:e1:6d:d6:2f:9b:8f:5c:c3:bf:61:68:87:91:20:ee:d1:65
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA
        Validity
            Not Before: May  7 14:29:32 2024 GMT
            Not After : May  2 14:29:32 2044 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyClient
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c5:49:04:16:64:8a:41:2a:1c:03:c2:6b:90:04:
                    13:c1:a1:3d:bf:83:10:63:60:88:f8:1f:83:49:fe:
                    93:42:5c:8b:05:a3:e2:d5:3d:9d:24:41:a7:2b:82:
                    60:0b:51:8f:43:ac:b9:ac:cf:7d:45:6a:8c:bc:2b:
                    fe:6d:38:b9:38:16:5d:23:54:fc:83:b4:8b:6d:37:
                    1e:39:07:ab:a6:80:f5:78:33:30:cf:de:1e:0e:b0:
                    a0:90:98:e2:0c:9e:52:76:96:f3:b4:48:ce:4c:02:
                    fd:a4:dd:d9:cf:bf:2e:e9:b3:07:54:8d:d6:d1:83:
                    65:ba:96:13:6e:b9:0d:0e:50:11:c4:85:53:9e:a7:
                    87:de:47:c4:95:10:d0:5d:59:a4:1a:91:0c:96:eb:
                    90:67:07:91:90:36:d0:84:83:c4:1b:76:1c:5b:bc:
                    c1:db:4e:2a:8e:c0:cd:57:90:b8:50:43:36:88:e9:
                    f4:83:37:70:a4:bf:9b:24:78:09:89:fb:25:86:cf:
                    1a:70:4f:cb:6c:ef:83:b1:ad:07:cc:96:d8:84:f8:
                    f2:45:79:32:81:56:20:b2:92:b7:e5:c8:cc:86:ad:
                    f1:68:6a:06:f2:0d:8e:af:71:54:5f:cc:fd:53:f8:
                    53:e6:da:3f:b1:ec:43:19:dd:01:c4:78:86:11:70:
                    09:59
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                8A:41:B1:DF:3A:EC:B8:77:FE:C1:09:27:C5:55:CF:DE:AE:A0:06:28
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                3A:F0:3E:1C:D2:7B:44:15:F6:EA:8B:ED:2B:9B:94:3C:66:7B:AE:F4
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        1d:07:ff:7e:52:1a:c0:1d:23:5c:1f:91:1a:cc:26:2e:37:26:
        68:c4:25:e2:e7:3d:4a:5a:76:fb:aa:ec:00:2b:8f:2f:30:d9:
        aa:4e:5e:82:76:06:4f:3a:57:8e:8c:99:59:f3:86:5d:6c:50:
        44:1a:82:2e:b6:ff:47:e8:6a:c9:0a:06:5f:50:71:74:91:c4:
        44:54:cf:b0:9c:25:70:b4:a9:f0:af:2c:43:8d:90:06:0a:8b:
        7c:29:93:cb:2c:96:e9:5f:86:d5:55:1f:03:1c:15:15:bb:fb:
        3e:c6:90:cd:f6:b2:14:d4:46:1a:31:56:1e:cd:0b:b5:9d:57:
        65:61:c5:6b:f3:c9:40:76:ee:f0:94:a2:d5:68:45:59:24:ca:
        39:7b:b0:5e:6f:ef:53:73:d5:ea:10:89:41:10:8b:c5:7a:5e:
        37:37:cc:ec:ee:ac:ba:bb:fb:04:3b:f0:ad:ee:7b:a7:2e:34:
        d9:36:4b:c2:53:95:c7:1f:4f:5a:0e:3a:6a:83:a9:14:b6:c1:
        37:23:68:4f:94:67:1b:a1:ae:a4:58:ca:09:a9:65:65:03:0a:
        67:16:b7:e2:df:07:09:23:f4:47:83:7a:bc:e7:be:c6:32:ee:
        49:cc:75:0b:e1:ce:83:48:41:9d:ca:af:86:20:e6:62:72:97:
        07:1d:16:1d
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----



Here is the updated Server Certificate:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            36:3a:28:e1:6d:d6:2f:9b:8f:5c:c3:bf:61:68:87:91:20:ee:d1:63
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA
        Validity
            Not Before: May  7 14:23:24 2024 GMT
            Not After : May  2 14:23:24 2044 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyServer
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c2:5b:ee:02:cf:15:5d:8c:5e:62:c9:ea:4d:c3:
                    59:e2:ee:d9:6f:c9:28:9d:c7:13:46:dd:f8:21:59:
                    a5:7a:d1:4f:10:14:7a:45:fd:c4:da:dc:cb:aa:35:
                    b0:c1:4c:77:8c:bb:74:28:42:3e:f3:ab:ed:2a:84:
                    d8:88:fe:fa:65:53:a0:3c:62:51:77:d3:ee:a5:c3:
                    8c:6e:59:9b:ca:46:a8:59:84:61:26:ed:83:79:59:
                    13:bb:bc:cb:3e:56:c6:7d:be:28:8a:92:ec:5a:96:
                    06:7c:3c:be:4d:1f:33:c2:16:e1:86:0a:43:1a:71:
                    6b:3f:3a:13:9e:30:29:9c:cb:7b:0f:18:fe:2a:52:
                    85:78:74:5c:ee:85:9b:e4:8b:a1:56:9f:7e:fe:c4:
                    69:a8:59:df:1d:13:3a:61:8f:a5:e4:db:69:05:3e:
                    91:b1:86:da:67:f3:c6:b7:52:23:e8:e4:55:7a:23:
                    c3:e3:73:9a:5f:6a:f7:0e:75:0a:25:48:cc:ec:6a:
                    f2:35:e4:1f:d2:f1:07:91:a3:1b:14:97:d0:2f:f9:
                    3e:af:b0:54:4c:44:90:1b:cc:22:56:cf:52:43:5c:
                    38:44:8f:7f:ca:8f:1b:bb:94:45:e8:f3:d9:63:6a:
                    9e:aa:79:8f:30:95:09:0a:96:84:70:7c:60:58:32:
                    98:3f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                F5:2E:4D:CC:E5:50:49:77:E5:B7:0E:B1:54:FC:C7:CD:05:E8:38:CD
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                3A:F0:3E:1C:D2:7B:44:15:F6:EA:8B:ED:2B:9B:94:3C:66:7B:AE:F4
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        55:e3:6b:3f:d6:3e:34:df:a7:4d:22:29:3a:74:be:16:54:e8:
        92:3e:54:8a:1b:55:18:ca:08:ce:91:9c:99:14:e3:74:56:84:
        3d:ea:18:d5:73:e1:ec:7e:ff:e5:71:ff:69:1c:34:e9:c2:68:
        6d:56:31:4a:1a:bf:41:8a:71:5f:4a:1f:6e:73:52:c0:a6:0e:
        97:3a:6e:40:c3:74:60:87:74:be:59:d8:9a:3f:20:f2:cc:fa:
        3b:79:7f:73:ea:5a:9c:07:27:6f:e1:86:71:21:6a:a7:c0:46:
        de:b0:a3:94:c0:76:65:47:4c:53:50:22:a8:6b:b6:99:d0:dc:
        c8:ff:d1:50:5a:e5:66:51:5f:aa:3a:40:d0:96:76:51:17:74:
        e8:05:41:5a:35:6b:b9:21:2e:50:bc:e7:f0:4d:05:43:b7:0b:
        fc:24:b3:28:c1:9b:83:ce:06:d0:61:77:f1:1f:26:f5:d3:79:
        ed:d4:1d:4b:29:91:73:a1:8a:0c:70:66:ea:4c:40:04:e6:11:
        92:cb:7f:c1:9e:1b:3e:27:33:44:60:f8:e0:63:11:ee:5c:f8:
        50:17:07:9b:e9:3b:0a:d5:37:80:3f:77:c5:cf:23:b8:f4:b5:
        d1:ae:ac:3b:d5:70:ba:ee:c8:05:a7:dc:7e:46:6d:63:59:74:
        a2:56:a1:95
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----




Here is my self-signed CA certificate in case this helps:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            66:6b:c1:c7:d4:53:96:c1:ad:d5:20:bc:5f:4f:c3:bf:63:87:46:f1
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA
        Validity
            Not Before: May  5 18:52:23 2024 GMT
            Not After : Apr 30 18:52:23 2044 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a3:2a:52:4c:2c:fa:56:a7:8e:79:07:43:b0:c6:
                    a9:f9:f2:ad:71:c6:fb:9d:ee:37:3e:08:e9:e9:ce:
                    5b:00:c9:76:f4:d6:2b:d7:ff:61:70:05:cf:5e:ee:
                    42:dc:76:bc:5a:b5:df:86:04:4a:0d:45:c0:c5:f4:
                    2a:cb:8b:22:35:66:80:be:89:89:f7:a7:42:76:55:
                    4e:9e:3b:69:37:df:a3:d3:d2:5d:92:a2:ca:9d:5b:
                    1a:06:2a:d6:d0:49:d6:22:c7:64:db:42:88:6e:9f:
                    92:74:58:e1:ce:d0:fb:25:40:20:9a:a7:50:10:c2:
                    b4:4c:5a:d8:d5:ec:71:06:32:6f:1c:98:70:24:b5:
                    4f:f8:ef:1c:79:9b:0c:33:61:9f:87:3c:76:39:65:
                    4e:fe:cd:fd:6c:39:4e:3a:fe:a4:d9:ca:25:f1:92:
                    52:c1:fa:6a:3f:1a:67:d3:4b:2c:ab:90:6a:64:e9:
                    69:93:ec:55:6d:81:3f:c4:b0:b9:a8:d8:42:c0:f3:
                    5a:1b:df:fc:1a:3f:41:fb:bf:8c:c5:9c:32:72:c3:
                    e2:32:e8:32:5d:58:a3:ec:b9:22:7f:b2:6d:dc:ff:
                    19:f3:47:98:fb:3b:31:48:05:ce:47:86:88:d0:f7:
                    bf:27:9e:2c:82:41:46:58:e6:b6:44:f7:24:d0:16:
                    e4:b5
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                3A:F0:3E:1C:D2:7B:44:15:F6:EA:8B:ED:2B:9B:94:3C:66:7B:AE:F4
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                3A:F0:3E:1C:D2:7B:44:15:F6:EA:8B:ED:2B:9B:94:3C:66:7B:AE:F4
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        4e:54:b1:a8:ac:27:06:c5:0c:d5:c1:5c:a5:9f:28:a4:5d:b5:
        1b:6f:32:4b:40:25:49:cc:e5:0c:37:87:77:cd:6f:65:02:15:
        79:5a:1d:4c:90:eb:cc:af:87:b3:c1:f7:e1:e5:9d:e2:8d:59:
        03:7e:75:e7:88:67:0f:ec:6a:44:70:30:e2:df:3e:e0:d0:97:
        fa:37:57:7f:47:23:0b:e1:34:1a:d9:14:e2:fe:99:07:15:67:
        cc:e9:5a:19:9f:50:ae:23:40:7f:32:58:ef:db:fc:1f:6e:57:
        b8:b3:4e:6e:7e:85:89:a6:10:ac:69:e8:0e:53:16:f5:63:7f:
        78:a5:28:c5:7c:84:ce:35:f8:96:5b:df:32:1a:df:a9:9e:a6:
        92:3a:21:69:1e:fa:6e:6d:5f:99:5e:57:ed:4c:7c:85:f7:6c:
        ea:bf:09:d8:04:7e:4a:c3:3d:16:3c:e6:3f:8d:c7:5b:97:be:
        46:c7:6d:f4:d5:bc:44:6a:45:0f:71:9b:96:21:19:1c:7c:ff:
        55:5c:8f:a0:36:3f:66:d9:05:c2:b3:9d:3f:af:53:9c:b0:c2:
        d1:6e:ce:d1:37:02:56:ec:53:15:97:d0:cc:93:2c:fd:63:b0:
        d2:1f:fd:62:f8:74:8a:43:90:c5:f7:27:e5:8f:2d:79:38:64:
        e1:be:27:d7
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----



Finally here are the results when trying a testing ssl connection with tls1_2:
openssl s_client -connect 192.158.22.141:51761 -tls1_2
Can't use SSL_get_servername depth=1 C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami,
 O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA 
verify error:num=19:self-signed certificate
 in certificate chain verify return:1 depth=0 C = US, ST = Florida, L =
 Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyServer 
verify error:num=26:unsupported
 certificate purpose verify return:1 depth=1 C = US, ST = Florida, L =
 Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA 
verify return:1 depth=0 C = US, ST =
 Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyServer verify return:1
--- Certificate chain  0 s:C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyServer    i:C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA    a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256    v:NotBefore: May  5 18:59:32 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Apr 30 18:59:32 2044 GMT  1 s:C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA    
i:C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA    a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256   
v:NotBefore: May  5 18:52:23 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Apr 30 18:52:23 2044 GMT
--- Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDrjCCApagAwIBAgIUNjoo4W3WL5uPXMO/YWiHkSDu0V4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL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-----END CERTIFICATE----- subject=C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyServer issuer=C = US, ST = Florida, L = Miami, O = MyCompany, CN = MyCA
--- No client certificate CA names sent Peer signing digest: SHA256 Peer signature type: RSA-PSS Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
--- SSL handshake has read 2516 bytes and written 285 bytes 
Verification error: unsupported certificate purpose
--- New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS supported Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE No ALPN negotiated SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 870BC6133653B0D964122E527BD830E11788A0F3779E95AFD2F7BCB8572AFAD2
    Session-ID-ctx: 
      Master-Key: 63F9A2F94BADB62D4C764387B744494BD1CC7AD0530C11A142B3246776F691080F30826CFDC674E7631D33C23F7CE335
      PSK identity: None
      PSK identity hint: None
      SRP username: None
      TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
      TLS session ticket:
      0000 - ca 8a 8f e8 eb dd 54 84-50 4f da 82 50 f2 ff 8a   
      0010 - fe 1d 98 ff f6 25 ea 97-20 8c 71 b7 e3 11 bb d9   
      0020 - 8f 0d 35 b5 b7 72 d4 fb-ad 66 83 53 29 42 50 ca   
      0030 - 48 f6 b0 82 eb 67 26 3c-3a 66 1f e7 93 68 c0 19   
      0040 - 5b 01 4d 87 db d7 bf 8e-23 84 af 2e 6d 12 47 20   
      0050 - 1d 4e f2 96 a6 ba 92 69-05 c5 9f 36 f6 79 ca 26   
      0060 - 5c ac d8 3c 70 d1 ef 2c-15 32 0e 1c 9d 6d c3 e5   
      0070 - f0 44 2d 5f 96 68 32 9f-5a 6f 48 ad c3 3a db 8b   
      0080 - 3c 19 e9 84 3b a5 93 18-fb 57 8a b0 03 43 3e f7   
      0090 - cf c8 79 7d a2 de 66 d7-f3 20 37 cd 7b 84 40 3a   
 
      Start Time: 1715045293
      Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
      Verify return code: 26 (unsupported certificate purpose)
      Extended master secret: yes

I created a quick Java program to display all the supported cipher algorithms, and here are the results:  Supported Cipher Suites:
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA

What's the C++ server?  What TLS cipher suites does it support?  You can also set -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to have your JVM dump debug data about all SSL/TLS connections.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563289/how-can-i-get-debug-messages-from-javas-ssl-handshake and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Andrew, thank you for your response.   I did turn on debugging of ssl and posted my results in the original question.   Also the C++ Server is another application that someone in my company wrote, and I have all the source and can debug the C++ server as well.

You can ignore the disabled or unsupported cipher suites. You can cut down the output via -Djavax.net.debug=-ssl,handshake. What is of most interest here is the debug dump immediately before the exception is thrown.

Does this C++ server support TLSv1.2?  Look for jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in /path/to/jdk/..../jre/lib/security/java.security.  Everything older than TLSv1.2 is probably disabled.

Andrew, as far as I can tell the C++ server supports TLSv1.2.  Although the C++ server is using OpenSSL, and not java.. so would the C++ Server be looking at the java.security file??       Here's what's in the java.security jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms:  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, 
DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, 
include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

I did a test to confirm the server supports TLSv1.2..  I'll add the results to the original question, but I do see something in the response from the server that states:  Verify return code: 26 (unsupported certificate purpose).

I'm wondering if the unsupported certificate purpose for the MyServer certificate is due to  CA:TRUE in the certificate??    The MyServer certificate is not a CA, it's signed by the CA.   Could this be possible?

It won't help with TLS1.2, but it doesn't cause the NoSuchAlgorithmException. See RFC 5280.

trustStore provider is: [blank] doesn't look right. Wherever you have configured trustStoreType=PKCS11 you may need to configure trustStoreProvider as well. Unless it is the default ...

@user207421+ CLOSE! although basicConstraints=CA:TRUE is semantically wrong for a server cert, it does not cause the error; keyUsage=keyCertSign,cRLSign DOES cause verify error 46 in openssl s_client and in my Java 11 (Adoptium) it gives the exception quite different from what you posted and much clearer: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures

PS: root certs are always selfsigned, by definition. In PKI selfsigned doesn't mean signed by the same person; it means signed with the same keypair as is contained in the SPKI field. The root cert issued by Digicert or LetsEncrypt/ISRG etc is selfsigned and signed by them, and your (root) CA cert is selfsigned and signed by you. The server and client certs issued under your CA cert are not selfsigned even though you yourself signed them.

@dave_thompson_085, just to confirm you believe the NoSuchAlgorithmException that I'm seeing is due to an improper keyUsage in the server certificate?    I'm going to focus on that this morning.  Wondering what the proper keyUsage should be?  I'll be looking that up.

@dave_thompson_085, I update the keyUsage on the client and server certificates to be:
Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment  and removed keyCertSign an cRLSign from keyUsage on the server certificate.   Still getting the exact same error message.   I updated my original question with the latest versions of the client and server certificates.

@user207421, I'm relying on the default truststore provider.

Still waiting for the debug dump immediately prior to (and including) the exception.

@user207421,  Really appreciate your help on this!!   Can't state that enough.    I'll be glad to give you a debug dump.   Are you referring to the ssl debugging?   Or the java application debugging?     ssl debugging doesn't really output much..  I already gave all the ssl debugging in the original question.   I just did another test, and I'll put all the output with ssl debugging enabled in the next comment.

I am referring to 'what is of most interest here is the debug dump immediately before the exception is thrown' which I posted above. I am also referring to the output of javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake, which I also posted above. And don't post it in comments. You can see for yourself that it's totally illegible. Edit it into your question.

@user207421, thank you for the clarification.   I updated my original question with the output from javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake.   As you will see there's only a couple of lines in the output which refer to jdk.tls.keyLimits.    Perhaps given the very little loggingm  it doesn't appear the client and server are getting very far with the ssl handshake?     Perhaps that's a clue to help figure this out.

Sigh. I didn’t ask for the lines about keyLimits, and nor did I provide any clarification beyond what I had already asked for. Which you have still not provided.

The NoSuchAlgorithmException that I thought occurred during the ssl handshake is very misleading!! I've confirmed the error is actually happening on the Java SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(server, port) call just prior to the actual ssl handshake.     A Java stack trace is stating that it's having an issue accessing the Java Truststore.  Would be nice if Java could have stated in the error message "Can't access Truststore"!!!    All this time I'm thinking it must be a problem with the certificates or lack of a common cipher algorithm between the Java client and C++ server, but that's not the real issue here.  I'm not a Java developer and never have used openssl before, so it's been a challenge to figure this out.   Really appreciate everyone that took the time to answer my questions.

Jack, posting the entire stack trace would have made that obvious in the first place.
